# Cant connect to my Wi-Fi due password length

Tags: wi-fi, lg

Today I bought a LG L70 wich has android 4.4.2 and wanted to connect to my Wi-Fi, but after entering the password the "connect" button doesnt light up (it stay grey instead of black) it seems that the requiered characters to make it able to connect it's 5 and 13 characters, while my house password its 9 characters long, is there any way to make it able to input any lenght password?

My local wi-fi it's WEP, and I have no issues connecting to networks using WPA/WPA2, so this seems to be an issue with WEP only.

Comment: It would help to name the encryption standard used (WEP? WPA? WPA2?) The character length sounds strange to me; I was initially thinking it might require a HEX value instead of "plain text" (often the case with WEP) – but odd numbers make no sense with that either (and would rather be 26 chars then).

Comment: my local wi-fi it's WEP, a WPA2 PSK web let me input more that 8 characters

Comment: Every WEP, or WPA/WPA2 networks as well? Moreover: What type of WEP? 64bit or 128bit keylength? In the past I'd setup my router with the latter, and had 26 characters HEX to put in. Are you by any chance still using WEP64? In that case, you urgently should consider switching to something more secure! Takes a hacker only seconds to break that one.

Comment: I edited my comment, the only WEP network arround its mine, so i cant test on another, but if i try to input a password to any other network with WPA/WPA2 SPK i can input more than 8 characters and it allow me to connect, also i dont know if its 64 or 128 bit keylength ):

Comment: I've included these important details directly into your question (note you can always [edit] it, and should do so with key details like these). As already pointed out by my previous comment: best solution is switching to a more secure encryption on your home network. Could well be WEP is going to be dropped soon.

Comment: Yeah, I think that I'll grab my router manual and set a password with the desired length, according to this site http://www.andrewscompanies.com/tools/wep.asp WEP keys should be 5, 13, 16 or 29 characters long